# $(...).autoсomplete is not a function

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, autocomplete

Всем привет! 
Не понимаю в чем проблема. Подключен JS и библиотека автокомплит.

```
<link id="bs-css" href="css/bootstrap-cerulean.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/charisma-app.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href='bower_components/bootstrap-tour/build/css/bootstrap-tour.min.css' rel='stylesheet'>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap-datetimepicker/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css" />
<link href='bower_components/chosen/chosen.min.css' rel='stylesheet'>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="js/autocomplete/jquery.auto-complete.css">
<script src="bower_components/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
```

В теге head;

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/autocomplete/jquery.auto-complete.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="moment/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/moment2/moment.min.js"></script>

<script src="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/bootstrap-tour/build/js/bootstrap-tour.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="bootstrap-datetimepicker/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="php/admPan/admPan.js"></script>
```

И перед 
В скрипте admPan.js лежит

```
$("#cityTK").autoсomplete({})
```

При загрузке страницы выпадает ошибка

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).autoсomplete is not a function
```

Не понимаю что именно не так. Как исправить? Или я что то не так подключаю?

UPD:
Забыл добавить еще 1 библиотеку.

```
<script src="bower_components/chosen/chosen.jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Подключается так же перед закрывающимся body

Comment: А вы уверенны что подключили jquery.js до вызова  jquery.auto-complete.js ?

Comment: Ну по сути jq подключается в head.
А jquery.auto-complete.js перед </body>

Comment: Следовательно jq должен подключаться раньше

Comment: Ну если вы увернны что файлы jquery.js и jquery.auto-complete.js корректные библиотеки, то возможно у вас какой то конфликт. Для проверки удалите подключение других JS и оставьте только jquery и autocomplete

Comment: Отключил все, кроме этих двух файлов. Не помогло. Тогда стоит поискать другие версии jq и автокомплита?

Comment: Да, посмотрите тут https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

Comment: Уже скачал библиотеки оттуда и подключил. Результат к сожалению тот же

Comment: Но, запустив их же пример - работает. Буду разбираться в чем проблема.

Answer (score 1):

Переделал страницу по примеру. с  jqueryui.com/autocomplete 
Не нашел какая из библиотек выдавала конфликт. Подключил все обратно постепенно - все работает.

Comment: Чтобы дополнить свой вопрос, просим вас воспользоваться опцией редактирования. Кнопку «Опубликовать ответ» следует использовать только для исчерпывающих ответов на вопросы. - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/240722)

Comment: Ответ на вопрос должен ведь быть какой-то? Я дал ответ на свой вопрос.

Comment: "Ну я там что-то перебрал, не знаю в чем была проблема, но заработало" - слабо подходит под полезный ответ.

Comment: Согласен. Но другого нет. И разбираться в чем именно было дело тоже не вариант. И оставлять вопрос без ответа также не вариант, что бы попросту не писали ответы.